# Python - multiprocessing.Value not return assigned value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote code in two files. In order to point to the problem, i'm doing summary for the code

in **first.py**

```
def sim(self, x, y, num):
        sim = 0.999999
        num.value = sim
```

**second.py**

```
num = Value('d', 0.0)

p = Process(target=first.sim, args=(int(d * (k-1)), txtlen, num))                       
processes.append(p)
p.start()   

print num.value
```

I expect that the output should be `0.999999`. But it's only return `0.0`. How can i fix this problem? Can somebody please help?

my reference: [16.6.1.4. Sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using this code and it seems to work:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value

class First(object):
    def sim(self, x, y, num):
        sim = 0.999999
        num.value = sim


num = Value('d', 0.0)
first = First()
p = Process(target=first.sim, args=(0, 0, num))
p.start()
p.join()

print num.value
```

Seems like your process fails to finish, so you must ensure it finishes by using `p.join()` before accessing `num.value`